# Snippet of Firebase with ArrayAdapter. The error with this code happens whenever I am adding a new obj. It's added twice

Tags: android, listview, object, firebase, android-arrayadapter

This is a code snippet of Main Activity. In my editor activity I add a new object and when I return back to the Main Activity I see the record is showing twice.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
    // whenever data at this location is updated.
    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        n = (String) child.child("name").getValue();
        Log.e("Name is :", n);
        a = (String) child.child("author").getValue();
        cc = (String) child.child("code").getValue();
        cn = (String) child.child("course").getValue();
        c = (String) child.child("contact").getValue();
        r = (String) child.child("regno").getValue();
        b.add(new book(n, a, cn, cc, r, c));
    }
    BookAdapter itemsAdapter = new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this, b, R.color.listItem);
    listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the database structure?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my issue is resolved now.